# How do I insert an Identity column rather than a constant into a table in which the column is not an identity column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCustomerDetails
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(30),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(30),
    @Phone CHAR(30),
    @Email NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO Person.Person (BusinessEntityID, PersonType, NameStyle,Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix, EmailPromotion, AdditionalContactInfo)
            VALUES (20778, 'SC', 0, 'NULL', '@FirstName', '@MiddleName', '@LastName', 'NULL', '0', 'NULL');

            INSERT INTO Person.PersonPhone(BusinessEntityID, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberTypeID)
            VALUES (20778, '@Phone', 2);

            INSERT INTO Person.EmailAddress (BusinessEntityID, EmailAddressID, EmailAddress)
            VALUES (20778, '1', '@Email');

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        PRINT 'Roll back transaction'
    END CATCH
END
```

I don't intend to insert the value, 20778, into the columns of `BusinessEntity`. How do I call it from the original table (`Person.BusinessEntity`), where it is an identity column, using the last insert into these tables?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use MAX:

```
DECLARE @id int = (select max(BusinessEntityId) From Person.BusinessEntity)
```

Comment: This is highly susceptible to race condition issues in normal circumstances. In this case, with the transaction, it should be safe, but will instead tend to cause excessive locking  and create a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Roman.Pavelko Declaration of the variable, as you have done here, is all I need to do. However, I had to add this line "Set @id=@id+1" since the next ID value to the maximum is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @AderojuAdemola . . . This is absolutely not the right way to do this.  This is subject to errors with concurrent updates, for instance.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, What's your own suggestion?

Comment: @AderojuAdemola . . . I think I address that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the column in the first table is an identity field, you should use [`scope_idenity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) immediately after the first INSERT statement to get the result. Then use that result in the subsequent INSERT statements.

```
Create Procedure spCustomerDetails
    @FirstName nvarchar (30),
    @LastName nvarchar(30),
    @Phone Char(30),
    @Email nvarchar(30)
    As
Begin
    Begin Try
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
        Begin Transaction

        DECLARE @NewBusEntityID int;

        INSERT INTO Person.Person(PersonType, NameStyle,Title, FirstName, MiddleName,  LastName, Suffix, EmailPromotion, AdditionalContactInfo)
        VALUES('SC', 0, 'NULL', '@FirstName', '@MiddleName', '@LastName', 'NULL', '0', 'NULL');

        SELECT @NewBusEntityID = scope_idenity();

        INSERT INTO Person.PersonPhone(BusinessEntityID, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberTypeID)
        VALUES(@NewBusEntityID, '@Phone', 2);

        INSERT INTO Person.EmailAddress(BusinessEntityID,EmailAddressID,EmailAddress)
        VALUES(@NewBusEntityID, '1', '@Email');

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Rollback Transaction
        Print 'Roll back transaction'
    End Catch
End
```

If it were not an identity field, you could instead use a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Then you could select the [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the sequence at the beginning of the procedure and use that value for all three INSERT statements.

Comment: In the original question author mentioned that identity is used from Person.BusinessEntity, that does not have any inserts within current stored procedure/transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause.  This just works, regardless of triggers on tables, other transactions, sessions, and so on.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCustomerDetails (
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(30),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(30),
    @Phone CHAR(30),
    @Email NVARCHAR(30)
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE TABLE @id (BusinessEntityId INT);
    BEGIN TRY
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO Person.Person (BusinessEntityID, PersonType, NameStyle, Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix, EmailPromotion, AdditionalContactInfo)
                OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityId) INTO @ids
                VALUES (20778, 'SC', 0, NULL, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, NULL, '0', NULL);

            INSERT INTO Person.PersonPhone (BusinessEntityID, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberTypeID)
                SELECT i.BusinessEntityID, @Phone, 2
                FROM @ids i;

            INSERT INTO Person.EmailAddress (BusinessEntityID, EmailAddressID, EmailAddress)
                SELECT i.BusinessEntityID, 1, @Email
                FROM @ids;

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        PRINT 'Roll back transaction';
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Note that this also drops the single quotes around the parameters and `NULL`.  I assume you want parameter values and not constant strings for those.

Comment: This is an eye opener